# For Loop with sed textfile

Tags: linux, loops, sed

I tried this out, but it is not working. I was wondering if you could help me out:

I have several text files in a folder and I want to copy the lines 111 to 734 from file1 in that folder and add to the other textfiles in that folder.

```
sed -n 111,734p file1>patch

for i in *;
do sed -i 110rpatch;
done
```

What am I doing wrong??

thanks

Comment: For starters, you're not using `"$i"` on the `sed` command line. How would sed know what file to process. Also, `110rpatch` I guess means "read in patch at line 110", but did you test that? I wouldn't expect that to work on some seds (but I could be wrong). Good luck.

Comment: i tried this out before: sed -n 111,734p file1>patch & sed -i 110rpatch file2 and it worked

Comment: so do you still have a Q? Or can you delete this. Good luck.

Comment: my questions belongs to the loop. I don't know why my loop is not working. And thanks for your comment, but I get an error saying: sed: can't read 110rpatch:no such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite this as

```
sed -n 111,734p file1>patch

for i in *; do 
   case "$i" in patch) continue ;; esac
   sed -i '110rpatch' "$i"
done
```

As the `patch` file is in the same dir as all the `$i` files, you need the case/continue test to skip processing the `patch` file.

IHTH